# Questions about install gruntjs

Tags: gruntjs

Im trying to start using gruntjs. But the official documentation is confusing me.

1. Should I write package.json file myself or any command would create it for me?
2. Uglify, concat, jshint all those plugins they used in the sample gruntfile, are they installed as grunt is installed?
3. When a plugin is installed, is it installed globally or I should install it everytime I create a new project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can write it yourself or create it with `npm init` or [grunt-init](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init).
2. No, you add the plugins you want to the package.json as `devDependencies`, then `npm install` to install them.
3. Plugins are project specific and are installed locally to your project.

Comment: And edit your dependencies by doing `npm install foo --save` which adds entries to your package json, including version numbers. Such a pain to look up otherwise. For development dependencies like node-unit  or mocha do `--save-dev` instead of `--save`